# How can I specifiy which delimiter a command line Hive query should return?

Tags: hive, delimiter, hiveql

I am using command line Hive. For example `hive -e "SELECT * FROM my_db.my_table;"`

It is currently returning what looks like tab separated values. Is it possible to specify which delimiter it should use? For example, can I make it return pipe separated values?

Answer (score 1):

```
  what i am done in my case, i fired a query like below.  

  INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/Desktop/test3'
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  select * from stud_02


  other solution would be 

   hive -e 'select *  from stud_01 limit 10' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' >> /home/Desktop/test.csv
```

Comment: What does `INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY` do?

Comment: Hi, it will create and insert the data in local file system directory